# Qual a utilidade de usar BaseColumns._ID para definir uma classe de contrato no SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Por que eu deveria usar [BaseColumns._ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) ao invés de simplesmente definir uma String como `_id` ?

Por exemplo, ao invés de usar:

- `public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;`

Não seria mais simples usar isto?

- `public static final String _ID = "_id";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na estrutura de suas tabelas, não há utilidade alguma e você pode definir simplesmente `public static final String _ID = "_id";`

Mas por quê existe essa constante no *Android*?

Essa constante serve para você ter o valor correto do campo `ID` quando for filtrar algo da base de dados do *Android*.

**Exemplo de como filtrar os logs de chamadas.**

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, BaseColumns._ID },
        BaseColumns._ID + " = ?",
        new String[] { "1" },
        CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " asc");
```

Observe que no código acima utilizamos `BaseColumns._ID`. Nesses casos é necessário utilizar dessa forma, isso porque o *Android* pode alterar esse valor do campo `ID` futuramente e com isso nosso código se mantém atualizado.

Já se usássemos `_id` (como no exemplo abaixo) nosso código já não funcionaria mais.

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, "_id" },
        "_id = ?",
        new String[] { "1" },
        CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " asc");
```

Portanto, quando for **sua estrutura** de dados, utilize da forma que preferir; Quando for utilizar a estrutura de dados do *Android*, utilize as constantes disponíveis.